# Using an NSManagedObject as an MKAnnotation causes MKMapView to Crash in newer devices

Tags: ios, swift, core-data, mkmapview, mkannotation

I have a class that inherits from `NSManagedObject` and also conforms to `MKAnnotation`. The code works perfectly fine on all iPhone models before iPhone X. But on iPhone Xs (X/XR/XS) the code crashes just after the annotations have been added to the `mapView`. And after two days of debugging, I've realised that everything works fine if I inherit from `NSObject` instead. However, this class is my main class and it's used in quite a number of places, so if possible, I'd like to avoid making huge changes to it.

Also, I'd like to know **WHY** `MKMapView` causes the app to crash on newer devices.

Below is a ***simplified*** version of the class. *NOTE: This simplified version is also crashing!!

```
import Foundation
import CoreData

@objc(TestLead)
class TestLead: NSManagedObject, MKAnnotation {

    @NSManaged public var dateModified: Date?
    @NSManaged public var localId: String?
    @NSManaged public var serverId: String?
    @NSManaged public var visibleCreated: Date?
    @NSManaged public var visibleModified: Date?

    init(context: NSManagedObjectContext, batch: Bool = false) {

        // create entity and insert into context
        let entity = type(of: self).entity(in: context)!
        super.init(entity: entity, insertInto: context)

        // provide random values for testing purposes
        self.localId = UUID().uuidString

        let date = Date()
        self.visibleCreated = date
        self.visibleModified = date
        self.dateModified = date
    }

    // MARK: MKAnnotation (Required by SRQuadTreeAnnotation)

    @objc
    public var coordinate: CLLocationCoordinate2D {
        get { return CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: 0, longitude: 0) }
    }

    /// Title to be shown in the callout for the annotation
    @objc
    public var title: String? { return "Test Lead" }
}


// MapViewController class
import Foundation
import MapKit
class MapViewController: UIViewController, MKMapViewDelegate {
    @IBOutlet weak var mapView: MKMapView

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        // Create a test annotation
        var allAnnotations: [MKAnnotation] = []
        let lead = TestLead(context: ManagedDocState.mainContext, batch: false)
        // add test annotation to our array of annotations
        allAnnotations.append(lead)

        // ->> crash happens on this line
        self.mapView.addAnnotations(allAnnotations)
    }
}
```

Insights on why this is happening, and perhaps how this can be **easily** resolved would be highly appreciated.

Comment: What is the error message?

Comment: `EXC_BAD_ACCESS at 0x0`